# Element.getElementsByTagName not working for me

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I am trying to parse a simple xsd file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
<xsd:element name="NickName" type="xsd:string">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            <Description>nick name</Description>
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I want to get the entire NickName element and I am using the following command

```
NodeList nodes = xsdDocument.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("element");
```

but I get null in the nodes. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to get all the nodes within the xsd that have the tag name as "element" Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should account for the namespace using [**Element.getElementsByTagNameNS()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagNameNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
NodeList nodes = xsdDocument.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "element");
```

Comment: I tried that earlier didnt work, Magically works now with the NameSpace..Thanks for assuring me that the ns was required.